# How to reset cascading select lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset, selectlist

I have three cascading select lists. When I try to reset them with this code:

```
function resetSearch(advancedSearch){
    document.getElementById("advancedSearch").reset();

    submitQuery();     
};
```

It resets the select lists, but because the select lists are cascading, so one depends on another to fill the select list with the correct values, it sets the values of the lists that are selected at that moment to the default.

So in my case I have three selectlists, one for the table names, one for the field names and one for the attributes. When I select a table it gives me the matching column names and attributes. If I than push teh reset button, it resets the table name to default, but the fieldnames and attribute select lists are set to the default of the other table.

Here is a picture to clarify my question:
[image]

This is my form with the select lists in it and the reset button;

```
 <form action="javascript:submitQuery()" id="advancedSearch">    
                                    <!-- Search by name input field -->
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <div id= "selectListContent">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div id="content-a">
                                                    <div class='content-row'>
                                                        <div class="select_table col-md-6">
                                                            <label for="invoerTabelNaam">Select table:</label>
                                                            <span>
                                                                <select class="form-control" name="table_names" id="slctTable">  
                                                                </select>
                                                            </span>    
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="select_column col-md-6">
                                                            <label for="invoerColumnNaam">Select column:</label>
                                                            <span>
                                                                <select class="form-control" name="column_names" id="slctField">
                                                                </select>
                                                            </span>    
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="select_attribute col-md-9">
                                                    <label for="invoerAttribuutNaam">Select attribute:</label>
                                                    <span>
                                                        <select class="form-control" name="attribute_names" id="slctAttribute">  
                                                        </select>
                                                    </span>    
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Buttons search en reset voor tab advanced search -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="resetSearch()">
                                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp Reset
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more code or working example with the same problem

Comment: $("select").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 });

Comment: shared some more code. The problem is that i dynamically fill the select lists from my DB so i can't give a working example srry.

Comment: Tryed you'r code @HudsonPH but still no luck. It's not displaying the columns and attributes of table 1.

Comment: I create this Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezmErd but I don't see your problem ? When I click on reset, all field are reseted.

Comment: Because you'r example has no cascading select list. When I select a table the second select list get's automatically filled with the refering column names.

Comment: I have do JS change to set dropdown conditionally and I don't see your problem => http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezmErd

Comment: Yeah because you have `table1 --> field 1 --> attribute 1`, but in my case i have `table1-->column name 1, column name 2, column name 3`. So the select list of column names (and attributes) get's filled with all the columns names of table 1 or table 2 depending on the selection that is made in the table name select list.

Comment: I have do fixes and I have dynamicly poppulated Dropdown now but... I don't see your problem => http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezmErd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have some event which populates other `selects` when value in first `select` is chosen. In that case you need to trigger it after form is reset.
For e.g.:

```
function resetSearch() {
  $('#slctTable').closest('form')[0].reset();
  $('#slctTable').trigger('change');
}
```

To clarify: how `reset` could 'know' that for 'table 1' correct list of fields is 'field1' and 'field2' and for 'table 2' it is 'other1' and 'other2'? It can just set selection to first items of lists.

```js
var data = {
  'table1': {
    'tab1_column1': ['tab1_col1_attr_1', 'tab1_col1_attr_2'],
    'tab1_column2': ['tab1_col2_attr_1', 'tab1_col2_attr_2']
  },
  'table2': {
    'tab2_column1': ['tab2_col1_attr_1', 'tab2_col1_attr_2'],
    'tab2_column2': ['tab2_col2_attr_1', 'tab2_col2_attr_2']
  }
}

function resetSearch() {

  $('#slctTable').closest('form')[0].reset();
  $('#slctTable').trigger('change');
}

$(function() {
  var table = $('#slctTable'),
    field = $('#slctField'),
    attr = $('#slctAttribute');

  table.on('change', function() {
    field.html('').val('');
    $.each(data[$(this).val()], function(k, v) {
      field.append($("<option />").val(k).text(k))
    });
    field.trigger('change');
  });
  field.on('change', function() {
    attr.html('').val('');
    $.each(data[table.val()][$(this).val()], function(k, v) {
      attr.append($("<option />").val(v).text(v))
    });
  });
  $.each(data, function(k, val) {
    table.append($("<option />").val(k).text(k))
  });
  //populate fields for the first time
  table.trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:submitQuery()" id="advancedSearch">
  <!-- Search by name input field -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div id="selectListContent">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="content-a">
          <div class='content-row'>
            <div class="select_table col-md-6">
              <label for="invoerTabelNaam">Select table:</label>
              <span>
                                                                <select class="form-control" name="table_names" id="slctTable">  
                                                                </select>
                                                            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="select_column col-md-6">
              <label for="invoerColumnNaam">Select column:</label>
              <span>
                                                                <select class="form-control" name="column_names" id="slctField">
                                                                </select>
                                                            </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="select_attribute col-md-9">
          <label for="invoerAttribuutNaam">Select attribute:</label>
          <span>
                                                        <select class="form-control" name="attribute_names" id="slctAttribute">  
                                                        </select>
                                                    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Buttons search en reset voor tab advanced search -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="resetSearch()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I needed to fire the .trigger('change') to invoke the field and attribute select list. I will tag your solution as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function resetSearch(advancedSearch){
```

change for this:

```
function resetSearch(){
```

Comment: Tryed you'r suggestion but it's still giving the default values of the columns and attribute index of table two.

Answer (score 0):

I have create from your initial HTML and description this Codepen with cascading population of field. I do not see your problem. Could you provide more explaination or to say if this resolve your problem?

> Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezmErd

*HTML*

```
<form class="container" action="javascript:submitQuery()" id="advancedSearch">
  <div class="form-group">

    <div id="selectListContent">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="content-a">
          <div class='content-row'>
            <div class="select_table col-md-6">
              <label for="invoerTabelNaam">Select table:</label>
              <span>
               <select class="form-control" name="table_names" id="slctTable">
                </select>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="select_column col-md-6">
              <label for="invoerColumnNaam">Select column:</label>
              <span>
                <select class="form-control" name="column_names" id="slctField">
                </select>
               </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="select_attribute col-md-9">
          <label for="invoerAttribuutNaam">Select attribute:</label>
          <span>
              <select class="form-control" name="attribute_names" id="slctAttribute">
              </select>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="resetSearch('advancedSearch')">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

*JS*

```
var table = document.getElementById("slctTable"),
  field = document.getElementById("slctField"),
  attrib = document.getElementById("slctAttribute"),
  populate = function (dropdown, name) {
    for (var i = 0, temp; i < 4; i++) {
      temp = document.createElement("option")
      temp.value = i + 1;
      temp.textContent = name + " " + +(i + 1);
      dropdown.appendChild(temp);
    }
  },
  submitQuery = function () {
    console.log("Submit !");
  },
  resetSearch = function (advancedSearch) {
    document.getElementById(advancedSearch).reset();
    submitQuery();
  };

// Populate dynamicly the first Dropdown.
populate(table, "Table");

// When you select an item of first Dropdown...
table.addEventListener("change", function() {
  field.innerHTML = "";
  // ...populate dynamicly the second Dropdown.
  populate(field, "Field");
});

// When you select an item of second Dropdown...
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  attrib.innerHTML = "";
  // ...populate dynamicly the last Dropdown.
  populate(attrib, "Attribute");
});
```